# How to adapt multithreaded observer-computation-rate to a cold Observable<List<T>>

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a Source as a cold `Observable<List<T>>` that emits elements in chunks (lists), I want to process every single item from the chunk in a separate thread, while the emiter (source) is waiting for termination of processing all items from the emited chunk to proceed with the next one and so on.

This code (rxjava 2.0.6) do the stuff but only in one Thread. If I want to fork the observer-computation in many Threads with `observeOn(Schedulers.io)`, the source-thread continue emiting everything until completed and do not block by every chunk.

```
Observable<List<T>> lazy_source = Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<List<T>> e)
        -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        List<T> chunk = produceChunkOf(10);
        e.onNext(chunk);
    }

    e.onComplete();
});    
lazy_source
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(chunk -> 
                Observable.fromIterable(chunk)
                    // .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // Uncommenting this will flat all 1000 chunks at once.
                    .doOnNext(item -> consume(item))
                , 10) // Number of concurent Threads
        .subscribe();
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
 Observable.range(0, 1000)
            .concatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(Integer integer) {
                    return produceChunkOf(10)
                            .flatMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<?>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<?> call(Object item) {
                                    return consume(item)
                                            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
                                }
                            }, 10)
                            .toList();
                }
            });
```

first, you create an `Observable` that emits the inputs to the `produceChunkOf`, then for each input item,you `concatMap` for your requirement for sequential execution for each chunk, for each input you produce the chunk , and process it in parallel with `flatMap`, then collect it after all items processed using toList()

Answer (score 0):

here is the final version (without overhead):

```
Observable.range(0, 1_000_000)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .concatMap(i -> produceChunkOf(100) // this returs an Observable of 100 items
                .flatMap(item -> Observable
                        .just(item)
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .doOnNext(element -> consume(element)), 
                        50)) // Number of concurent Threads
        .subscribe();
```